# Issue with CoreWLAN on MAC 10.7 (CoreWLAN Wireless manager sample)

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, osx-lion, corewlan

I just got the CoreWLANWirelessManager sample off apple site and i am trying to make it spin on OS 10.7.4.

The issue i'm having is a missing header : CoreWLANPrivate.h which is called from CoreWLAN.h

Anyone having the same problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a clean re-installation of Xcode4 fixed this issue.